# Sum indexed over set

Tags: summation, partitions

Say I have `sets = {{a,b},{c,d},{e,f}}` and I want to compute a sum like `f[a,b] + f[c,d] + f[e,f]`. One way to do this is to do

```
Sum[f[sets[[nSet]][[1]], sets[[nSet]][[2]]], {nSet, 1, Length[sets]}]
```

but this makes the notation cumbersome. It would be ideal to do something like

```
Sum[f[set[[1]], set[[2]]], set ∈ sets]
```

However, the function `Sum[]` doesn't allow indexation over abstract set other than a list of numbers. How can I implement this?

I'm asking because I need to do a lengthy computation involving sums and products over partitions, sets and mappings. And with the first option I wrote it really gets unhandleable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The summation index can run over a set, but instead of `set ∈ sets` the syntax is

```
Sum[f[set[[1]],set[[2]]],{set,sets}]
(* f[a,b]+f[c,d]+f[e,f] *)
```

I would probably use

```
Total[f@@@sets]
(* f[a,b]+f[c,d]+f[e,f] *)
```

This uses:

- `@@@` which is a shorthand for [`MapApply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapApply.html). Evaluate `f@@@sets` to see what it does.
- The [`Total`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html) function which adds all elements of a list.

Comment: Beautiful, it was so simple. I still have a lot of syntax to learn from Mathematica. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Also,

```
Inner[f, Sequence @@ Transpose@{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, g}}, Plus]
```

Answer (score 7):

Just another way:

```
Total@MapThread[f[#1, #2] &, Transpose@sets]
(*f[a, b] + f[c, d] + f[e, f]*)
```

Answer (score 6):

One possible way out of many is

```
lis = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}
Plus @@ Map[f[Sequence @@ #] &, lis]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Had to use `Sequence @@ #` in there, because just doing

```
Map[f, lis]
```

Gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Instead of the following when using `Sequence @@ #`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`@@` can be replaced by `Apply` if you prefer that.

Comment: Same comment I made above. Sorry I can't yet upvote and I can only accept one answer. It was helpful to see more options though. Thanks!